# Sitecore SXA action call a controller action

Tags: mvc, mvc-forms

how to create a button in Sitecore SXA which would call a controller action or a rest Api ?

would it be through javascript or is there an ootb feature in SXA , where i could get the user and item context ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is not **SXA** specific question. It's Sitecore MVC question.

You can see how it's done for **Login**, **Logout** renderings. Both of them use `Html.BeginForm()` helper. The disadvantage of this is that page will reload once you click submit button. At the same time, it is good because there is security protection (`@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`) against cross-site request forgery.

Another way would be JS call (AJAX Request) but there is no snippet for that in the SXA code.

You should review the answers for those keywords:
["call controller action sitecore mvc"](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/search?q=call%20controller%20action%20sitecore%20mvc)

I am sure you will find something.

Comment: Best way to utilise the Ajax call for controller method